# Error: Android/Sdk/build-tools/21.0.2/aapt.exe finished with non-zero exit value 42

Tags: java, android

I am getting the following error: `Error:Error: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'Android\Sdk\build-tools\21.0.2\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 42`

This is my gradle file:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 10
    targetSdkVersion 21
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

I've tried cleaning and rebuilding the project but it doesn't work. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Try different build tools, for example 21.0.1. But firstly check what build tools you have installed